# Передача одного mut замыкания на две и более структуры

Tags: rust

**Цель:** Раздать одно mut замыкание на две структуры. Если использовать одну структуру с принимающей замыкание то все работает хорошо.

**Облегченный код:**

```
fn main() {
    let mut is_visible = true;
    let mut is_close = true;

    let mut function = |name:Option<&[u8]>, value:&[u8]| {
        if let Some(name) = name {
            match name {
                b"is_visible" => {
                    is_visible = match value {
                        b"ON" => true,
                        b"OFF" => false,
                        _=>  false,
                    };
                },
                _=>{},
            }
        }
    };

    Test::test_set_vars(&mut function);
    Test2::test_set_vars(&mut function);

    if is_visible {
        println!("VISIBLE OK");
    }
    if is_close {
        println!("CLOSE OK");
    }
}



pub struct Test {

}

impl Test {
    pub fn test_set_vars<F: FnMut(Option<&[u8]>, &[u8])>(mut function: F) {
        function(Some(b"is_close"), b"OFF");
        function(Some(b"is_visible"), b"ON");
    }
}


pub struct Test2 {

}

impl Test2 {
    pub fn test_set_vars<F: FnMut(Option<&[u8]>, &[u8])>(mut function: F) {
        function(Some(b"is_close"), b"ON");
        function(Some(b"is_visible"), b"ON");
    }
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f3d656088b19ee1b847db54036983584&version=stable

*Если продублировать замыкание то все идет хорошо.*

**Код 2:**

```
fn main() {
    let mut is_visible = true;
    let mut is_close = true;


    Test::test_set_vars(|name:Option<&[u8]>, value:&[u8]| {
        if let Some(name) = name {
            match name {
                b"is_visible" => {
                    is_visible = match value {
                        b"ON" => true,
                        b"OFF" => false,
                        _=>  false,
                    };
                },
                _=>{},
            }
        }
    });
    Test2::test_set_vars(|name:Option<&[u8]>, value:&[u8]| {
        if let Some(name) = name {
            match name {
                b"is_visible" => {
                    is_visible = match value {
                        b"ON" => true,
                        b"OFF" => false,
                        _=>  false,
                    };
                },
                _=>{},
            }
        }
    });

    if is_visible {
        println!("VISIBLE OK");
    }
    if is_close {
        println!("CLOSE OK");
    }
}



pub struct Test {

}

impl Test {
    pub fn test_set_vars<F: FnMut(Option<&[u8]>, &[u8])>(mut function: F) {
        function(Some(b"is_close"), b"OFF");
        function(Some(b"is_visible"), b"ON");
    }
}


pub struct Test2 {

}

impl Test2 {
    pub fn test_set_vars<F: FnMut(Option<&[u8]>, &[u8])>(mut function: F) {
        function(Some(b"is_close"), b"ON");
        function(Some(b"is_visible"), b"ON");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема не в передаче замыкания в две функции, а в том, что замыкание захватывает мутабельную ссылку на `is_visible`, которая остаётся активной до конца жизни замыкания.

Можно ограничить время жизни замыкания, поместив его в блок. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=27ceea56f75f67d8595c40c8c3ba79af&version=stable)

Или использовать нелексические времена жизни из ночной ветки компилятора: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=df2edc19c4370b312ec61956e632cdf0&version=nightly)

Comment: Оболденно, работает. Не всегда приходит в голову ограничить время жизни.